# More advance entity join in FormBuilder Symfony2

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms, formbuilder, doctrine-query

I have two entities. First is `Clinic` an second is `ClinicOpeningHours`.

`ClinicOpeningHours` is mapped by `Clinic` id, but not in revers. I'm trying to find solution to get whole (7) records (mon - sun) and join it in `ClinicFormType` to have all this in one form.

```
$clinic = $em->getRepository('MyEntity:Clinic')->findOneBy(array(etc));
$form = $this->createForm(new ClinicFormType(), $clinic);
```

My form type:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
    $builder->add('name', 'text', array('label' => 'Name'));
    $builder->add('services', 'entity', array(
                'class' => 'MyEntity:Service',
                'property' => 'name',
                'label' => 'Services',
                'required' => false,
                'multiple' => true,
                'attr' => array(
                    'data-placeholder' => "Choose one...",
                    'multiple' => 'multiple',
                    'class' => "chzn-select"
                )
            ))
            ->add('WEEK DAYS', 'entity', array(
                'label' => 'Property Language',
                'class' => 'MyEntity:ClinicOpeningHours',
                'query_builder' => SEVER RECORDS FROM DB MAPPED BY ID
                },
            ));
}
```

Comment: Have you seen: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html

Comment: Yes i saw it, but i couldn't find explanation for my problem

Comment: I do not understand the question. What's the problem? You have a many-to-many relation?

Comment: No, i have many-to-one (ClinicOpeningHours - Clinic)